# Where does a developer put custom python libraries for import

Tags: python

I see a piece of legacy python code that is importing a library :
import cust_search as cs
Now on the entire machine, I cannot find any cust_search.py

What is this library?

Comment: Does the import work?

Comment: "I cannot find any cust_search.py" There might not be any if it is a C extension.

Comment: You can just do `cs.__file__` to try searching for your file @Victor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__file__` attribute to look up where it might be located, example

```
In [26]: import numpy as np                                                                                                    

In [27]: np.__file__                                                                                                           
Out[27]: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'
```

Similary, you can try

```
import cust_search as cs
print(cs.__file__)
```